# Java not accepting Module Names and other Variables

Tags: java, module

Today I come to ask for assistance because my code is the way I want it to be, however, I get many errors so i am starting to believe i cannot use my module names and other such terms. I am very lost, i have searched all over but nothing can explain to me how come my module names are "Illegal". I have copy and pasted them here in case you find it helpful. I am very confused because as you can see most of my "errors" come from my while, for, and the beginning of most of my module's.

**Errors:**

```
    Lab8_5.java:12: error: illegal start of expression
                public static int []notGreenCost = new int[6];
                ^
Lab8_5.java:17: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
                getNotGreen();
                ^
Lab8_5.java:18: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
                getGoneGreen();
                ^
Lab8_5.java:19: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
                energySaved();
                ^
Lab8_5.java:20: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
                displayInfo();
                ^
Lab8_5.java:22: error: illegal start of type
                while(endProgram.equals("no")) {
                ^
Lab8_5.java:22: error: <identifier> expected
                while(endProgram.equals("no")) {
                                       ^
Lab8_5.java:22: error: illegal start of type
                while(endProgram.equals("no")) {
                                        ^rrors
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab8_5 {
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare variables
        public static int []notGreenCost = new int[6];
        public static int []goneGreenCost = new int[6];
        public static String []months = {"January","Februarry","March","April","May","June"};

        // Module calls
        getNotGreen();
        getGoneGreen();
        energySaved();
        displayInfo();

        while(endProgram.equals("no")) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to run again: yes or no");
            endProgram = keyboard.nextLine();
            while (!(endProgram.equals("yes")) && !(endProgram.equals("no"))){
                System.out.println("Please enter a value of yes or no");
                endProgram = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }
    // getNotGreen module
    static void getNotGreen(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int ctr=0;ctr<6;ctr++){
          System.out.println("Enter NOT GREEN energy costs for: "+months[ctr]);
          notGreenCost[ctr]= keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }
    // getGoneGreen module
    static void getGoneGreen(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int ctr=0;ctr<6;ctr++){
          System.out.println("Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for: "+months[ctr]);
          goneGreenCost[ctr]= keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }
    // energySaved module
    static void energySaved(){
    for(int ctr=0;ctr<6;ctr++){

        }
    }
    // diplayInfo module
    static void displayInfo(){
    System.out.println("Savings       "+"Not Green       "+"Gone Green   "+"Months");
    for(int ctr=0;ctr<6;ctr++){
        System.out.println((notGreenCost[ctr]-goneGreenCost[ctr])+"           "+notGreenCost[ctr]+"             "+goneGreenCost[ctr]+"          "+months[ctr]);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your errors are syntax errors. I hope you find them for your homework assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra "}" in your code right after the main method.

```
}   =======>EXTRA 
    // getNotGreen module
    static void getNotGreen(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int ctr=0;ctr<6;ctr++){
          System.out.println("Enter NOT GREEN energy costs for: "+months[ctr]);
          notGreenCost[ctr]=in.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Also the local variables (variables inside a method) do not take any access modifier like "public" "private"
Change the below

```
 public static int []notGreenCost = new int[6];
        public static int []goneGreenCost = new int[6];
        public static String []months = {"January","Februarry","March","April","May","June"};
```

TO

```
 int []notGreenCost = new int[6];
  int []goneGreenCost = new int[6];
  String []months = {"January","Februarry","March","April","May","June"};
```

I would suggest to read more , only when you have understood the theory and syntax then type and verify the program . :)

Comment: Thank you! However i don't understand why it still wont accept the other Modules as u can see above, i have updated the list of errors.

Comment: Thnak you so much you are a life saver <3 I now understand the erorrs better thanks to you :D